# Maui StringFormat in label, possible to change FontAttribute inline?

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui, string-formatting

Really basic question, but I can't find the answer:

Is it possible to change the font attribute of a string in a label that's been formatted?

Specifically, I have this `Label`:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"
       Text="{Binding TimeStart, StringFormat='Time start: {0:F0}'}" />
```

It ends up looking like this:

> Time start: 13:32:46

When I would like it to look like this:

> **Time start**: 13:32:46

Or this:

> Time start: *13:32:46*

Is this possible to do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/label shows you need to use Label.FormattedText where FormattedString contains multiple Span elements. You cannot do it with StringFormat.

Comment: Yeah, I read that and didn't see an answer either.  I suppose you can't think of a workaround?  (I could remove the string formatting and just put two elements next to each other, the text `Time start:` and the bound label `13:32:46 (or whatever the Time is)`.  That's probably the best way.)

Comment: Simplistically, yeah, two Labels. If you want to get super fancy you could have a pseudo HTML parser or MarkDown parser that explodes an input text into a List/Collection of text elements that you could use to populate a FlexLayout with a BindableLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're curious I have a working version of the string splitter. Assuming your ViewModel has the `string Message` set to `"Time Start: *13:32:46*"`, here's how you may go about exploding that into formatted text with Regex:

```cs
public class FormattedText
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color TextColor { get; set; } = Colors.Black;
    public FontAttributes FontAttributes { get; set; } = FontAttributes.None;
}
```

Then, you can define a getter for `IList<FormattedText> FormattedMessage` using the following:

```cs
public IList<FormattedText> GetFormattedMessage(string message)
{
    List<FormattedText> Result = new List<FormattedText>();
    string pat = @"\*([^\*]*)\*|([^*]+)";
    Match match = Regex.Match(message, pat);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        if (match.Groups[1].Success)
        {
            Result.Add(new FormattedText() { Text = match.Groups[1].Value, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic});
        }
        if (match.Groups[2].Success)
        {
            Result.Add(new FormattedText() { Text = match.Groups[2].Value, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None });
        }
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Then, you can render the `FormattedMessage` in `FlexLayout` in XAML:

```xml
<FlexLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FormattedMessage}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                   TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                   FontAttributes="{Binding FontAttributes}"
                   Padding="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```